# Building lirc package from source with patches

Tags: apt, compiling, lirc

I'd like to build latest lirc package for 12.04 with two patches from [here](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=4ebf97df-17f8-48bb-ba65-32e4b9983ac4@devleno&forum_name=lirc-list) to make USB Infrared toy v2 work:

Running `sudo apt-build source lirc` gave me

```
➜  build  ll
total 960
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root   4096 Nov  5 07:07 lirc-0.9.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 113909 May  5  2011 lirc_0.9.0-0ubuntu1.debian.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1553 May  5  2011 lirc_0.9.0-0ubuntu1.dsc
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 857286 May  5  2011 lirc_0.9.0.orig.tar.bz2
```

in `/var/cache/apt-build/build`. Running `sudo apt-build build-source lirc` then gave me `Some error occured building package` which is not really informative.

I have successfully built patched lirc from git source but now I would like to get a deb package. Where can I look for this 'some errors' in detail?

This error appears regardless of patches applied or not. If someone could suggest another way of building latest lirc package I will really appreciate.